# Download .txt using JavaScript without dialog prompt

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create and download a .txt file using only JavaScript (no server-side programming !), and save it on local drive, without displaying browser "Save file" dialog ?

Comment: Imagine a world where any webpage could write to your local file system without asking you...

Comment: Well, you can store texts in [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) or in a [sandboxed filesystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System), but not directly on a specific drive.

Comment: it's easy, others on here so far are wrong. use http://danml.com/download.html if you want to save many files, you have to confirm once after the 2nd or 3rd download, but then you can download all day without further clicks.

Comment: @Bergi - There is no sandboxed filesystem. The previous File System API has been [cancelled](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html) and should not be [referenced](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/).

Comment: @dandavis: None of the examples there work for me without showing a file-save dialog. And it would be very unintuitive anyway.

Comment: @Bergi: asking or auto-saving is a browser pref. i can download 5 files on that page with 5 clicks, and if i use setInterval, it downloads files all afternoon w/o intervention, at least in chrome...

Comment: @Bergi: in chrome, the relevant setting is "Ask where to save each file before downloading", which should be un-checked to allow auto-downloading. In firefox, the pref appears on the download dialog itself: "Save File" + " () Do this automatically for files like this from now on". Once the pref is changed on either browser, downloading can proceed un-assisted by the human touch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Rickard Staaf*'s answer is outdated.
To download a file in javascript locally without prompting a dialog box, be sure to enable it in your browser settings (chrome >> settings >> advanced >> downloads and turn off *'Ask where to save each file before downloading'*.

Subsequently, you can write a simple text file like so using `blob` objects:

```
function save() {
  var content = ["your-content-here"];
  var bl = new Blob(content, {type: "text/plain"});
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(bl);
  a.download = "your-download-name-here.txt";
  a.hidden = true;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
}
```

Comment: I love it! Very useful.

Answer (score 5):

No not without browser plugins, that would be a big security risk.