# Implement autosave from browser to device with only one dialog prompt

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, draw.io

In a site I'm implementing, users save files on their local device. I want to implement autosave, but questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25826573/362702) convinced me it wasn't possible without a "File Save" dialog for every write to the file system (unless the user modifies their default browser settings).

However, I see that [app.diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/) does it! Once I specify a file path via an initial dialog my edits are autosaved without additional dialogs. That project is [open-source](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio), but my efforts to find the relevant code have so far not succeeded.

Anybody know how it's done?

Here are the steps to demonstrate that it's possible:

1. Browse to [app.diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/)
2. In the "Save diagrams to" dialog, choose "Device"
3. "Create New Diagram"
4. "Create"
5. In the "Save as" dialog, enter a filename
6. Make some edits
7. Reload the page
8. "Open Existing Diagram"
9. In the "Open" dialog, choose your file - it opens with your autosaved edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at the source and the apps.diagram.net is using the [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) to write to the file system.  If you keep the file handle around it will let you continue to create a writeable against it.   It requires that things are running from a secure context (https) to work.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
var fHnd = null;
var counter = 0;
var autoSaveOn = true;

window.onload = function() {

  var autoSave = async function() {
    if (autoSaveOn) {
      counter++;
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Saving...'
      const writable = await fHnd.createWritable();
      await writable.write(counter);
      await writable.close();
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
      window.setTimeout(autoSave, 3000);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('btnAutoSave').addEventListener('click', async() => {
    if (autoSaveOn) {
      autoSaveOn = false;
      document.getElementById('btnAutoSave').innerHTML = 'Turn autosave on';
    } else {
      autoSaveOn = true;
      document.getElementById('btnAutoSave').innerHTML = 'Turn autosave off';
      await autoSave();
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('btnCreateFile').addEventListener('click', async() => {
    fHnd = await window.showSaveFilePicker({
      types: [{
        description: 'Text Files',
        accept: {
          'text/plain': ['.txt']
        }
      }]
    });
    document.getElementById('btnCreateFile').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btnAutoSave').style.display = 'block';

    await autoSave();
  });

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script language="javascript" src="./sample.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btnCreateFile">Save to file</button>
  <p id="status"></p>
  <button id="btnAutoSave" style="display: none">Turn autosave off</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like browser support is spotty (https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api) … and trying https://app.diagrams.net on Safari (which doesn't support the API) I see there's a different UI requiring two clicks per save. Oh well, getting there.

Comment: Looks to me like a well-realized Google experiment, supported in Chromium browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera) but not likely to be supported elsewhere. The spec (https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access) says "It is not a W3C Standard nor is it on the W3C Standards Track."